# Git : Branch Merging Conflict Between Master And New Branch

Tags: git

I have 2 servers : example.com and example.net

and I have 2 git branches : master (example.com) and beta (example.net)

now, there's a file in master branch named `config.php` which contains database details :

```
$db_name : 'com_dbname';
```

when I create `beta` branch, I need to change this line so it can run on example.net :

```
$db_name : 'net_dbname';
```

so, `config.php` now is different from each branch. both branch now are committed and push to remote repository.

and development process still continue on master branch. I need to add some lines under the `$db_name` :

```
$db_name : 'com_dbname';
$other_var : 'other_value';
```

usually I can merge the master into beta branch on my bitbucket account. but since this file has changed, I can't merge master into beta branch. here's what it says :

This merge has conflicts that must be resolved before it can be committed.
To manually merge these changes into beta run the following commands:

```
$ git checkout 94c22fbaa758
# Note: This will create a detached head!
$ git merge remotes/origin/master
```

and here's the output on my terminal :

```
Note: checking out '94c22fbaa758'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at 94c22fb... 

git merge remotes/origin/master
Already up-to-date.
```

I'm confused. it says everything is already up to date, but I still see `1 commit behind master.` on my bitbucket and still unable to merge the master into beta branch.

please kindly help me. I really have no idea how to solve this and I'm using git just in last 2 months ago and never experience this branch merging situation before. thank you very much.

Comment: You wrote "here's what *it* says", but did not say what "it" is.  Some web page operation on bitbucket?

Comment: @torek : yes, it = bitbucket. on branch menu.

Comment: I have not used bitbucket myself (well, not since it was strictly Mercurial, and even then I was not writing to it), but it seems likely that you need to run `git fetch` first to bring any updates from the central repo on bitbucket into your local repo where you can work on it.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I generally employ with configuration files is to include a local file if it exists and **ignore it** from version control.

So let's say you are working on a php project and you have a default configuration file that's used in your master branch. The code to include it in the project might look something like this:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
```

Now in order to overwrite the values with the local configuration changes, you could check if it exists first, and then load it afterwards to overwrite values established in the default configuration file.

```
<?php
include("config.php");
if (file_exists("config.local.php"))
   require_once("config.local.php");
```

Alternatively from ignoring it from version control, if you for sure only merge from `master` to `beta`, which is highly unlikely especially given the implication behind the name of `beta` branch, then you could commit `config.local.php` to the `beta` branch and it wouldn't conflict when merging `master` into `beta`. But notice this would absolutely swoop in and override your default config if ever you merge from `beta` into `master` which is why I suggest ignoring the `local` config file in `.gitignore`. Admittedly, it's kind of a hassle to keep up with the environment specific differences (isn't that one reason why you opted for a version control system in the first place?), but from this example you're only really needing to change the `db_name`, which turns out to not be that big of a deal in my experience. Plus you could consider this as an added bonus  for securing credentials that aren't intended to be used anywhere else, so it sort of makes sense to not track them in version control when you're sharing this code with a team.